Why is sap.m.ActionSelect deprecated and what is the alternative?
As of version 1.111, sap.m.ActionSelect is deprecated. I could not find any explanation of why, and what I am supposed to use instead.

Were you able to contact SAP via the Fiori Makers email address?

According to the commit 7563ccb:

// @deprecated As of version 1.111 with no replacement. The control is no longer considered part of the Fiori concept.

The explanation is that Action Select is simply "no longer considered part of the Fiori concept."
Consider contacting "Fiori Makers" from SAP. Maybe you get a chance to ask for more clarity there.
